# How do I fix this strange Nginx / CherryPy behaviour when serving static files?

Tags: nginx, configuration, webserver, cherrypy

I am building a website which consists of a CherryPy application and some static files (CSS, JavaScript, images, et al). I am using Nginx as a reverse-proxy to serve the static files itself and to serve the application. I followed the configuration for this set-up as described here: [How to Deploy Python WSGI Applications Using a CherryPy Web Server Behind Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-a-cherrypy-web-server-behind-nginx).

But I am getting a strange behaviour from this configuration when trying to serve the static files. When any static file is requested, the content of the application is returned. For instance, I have two completely different files `wsgi.py` which returns an html document and `style.css`. If I navigate to `style.css`, it exists, but its content its content is the output of the application.

Additionally, anywhere I try to navigate, even to files that do not exist, the content returned is that of the application. But if I navigate to `localhost/static/*` I get a 404 error. Anywhere else (e.g. any gibberish like `localhost/asha9rghu/ay98394h/jasdhiuah`) and the content of the application is returned.

The error and access logs say everything is fine when the undesired content is being returned.

**Here is the set-up in its simplest form where the problem still exists:**

## Root Directory

```
cherrypy_app
     |
     |----server.py
     |----wsgi.py
     |----style.css
```

## server.py

```
from wsgi import application

import cherrypy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cherrypy.tree.graft(application, "/")

    cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()

    server = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()

    server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
    server.socket_port = 8080
    server.thread_pool = 30

    server.subscribe()

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

## wsgi.py

```
def website():
    website_html= """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Cute bunny rabbits.</p>
    </body>
</html>"""
    return (website_html)

def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
    return [website()]
```

## style.css

```
body{
    color:      #FFFFFF;
    background: #000000;
}
```

## nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    upstream app_servers {

        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
            root /home/user/cherrypy_app;
        }

    }

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies solely in the Nginx configuration file. The solution is simply to create one or more of the directories I specified and put the static files in them.

Essentially, in the configuration file, I have specified to Nginx that there are a number of directories (images, javascript, et cetera) and that they are located at /home/user/cherrypy_app. But in fact, those directories do not exist. So when Nginx receives a request for a file in one of those directories, it expects them to be there, but they are not. In which case, Nginx produces a 404 error.

```
#Specifies the existence of these directories
location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
    #specifies the location of the directories
    root /home/user/cherrypy_app;
```

I am not sure why I get the application content of the CherryPy application when I try to go to a file which explicitly does not exist. Maybe this a feature of CherryPy (redirect?). Either way, it is a non-issue at this point.